# Node.js sockets - Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID when trying to connect

Tags: node.js, sockets, ssl, certificate, wss

I am trying to move my Node.js socket from ws:// to wss://. ws:// version works fine. To make socket to be accessible from wss:// I have generated *.key and *.crt files with this command:

```
openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout privateKey.key -out certificate.crt
```

I set path to them in my js script and added few lines necessary to make it available from wss://. This is it:

```
    var fs=require('fs'),httpsServ=require('https'),cfg={port:55533,key:'/home/admin/web/ohrana.ua/public_html/sockets/certs/privateKey.key',cert:'/home/admin/web/ohrana.ua/public_html/sockets/certs/certificate.crt'};
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED="0";

var processRequest=function(req,res){
    res.writeHead(200); 
    res.end("OK"); 
};
  
var app=httpsServ.createServer({
   key:fs.readFileSync(cfg.key), 
   cert:fs.readFileSync(cfg.cert) 
},processRequest).listen(cfg.port);

var WebSocketServer=require('./ws/index.js').Server,ws=new WebSocketServer(/*{port:55533}/**/{server:app}),users={},test=true;
```

So now when I start socket server script with this command:

```
node /home/admin/web/ohrana.ua/public_html/sockets/webrtc.js
```

it starts without errors. But when I try to connect a socket from browser I have this error:

```
webrtc.html:68 WebSocket connection to 'wss://ohrana.ua:55533/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

This is how I connect to it from my browser:

```
var connection = new WebSocket('wss://'+window.location.hostname+':55533');
```

Cant really understand what is the problem. Can anyone shed some light on how to make it work and what I am doing wrong?

Any help appreciated!